Proof that $ch(K_{n,n^n}) = n + 1$
Promblem: 
I want to proof that $ch(K_{n,n^n}) = n + 1$ 
($K_{n,n^n}$ is the complete bipartite graph in which one of the classes has $n$ vertices, and
the other class has $n^n$ vertices.)
Idea: 
I tried to prove this statement using induction. It’s relatively easy to show that it holds for $K_{2,4}$.
Where I’m struggling is when I now consider $K_{n+1, (n+1)^{n+1}}$; then $K_{n, n^n}$ is an induced subgraph, so I know that $ch(K_{n+1, (n+1)^{n+1}}) \geq n+1$ must hold. However, I’m not really getting further from here. I initially tried to estimate it from above, but that didn’t help much. I’d appreciate any tips or perhaps a different approach to the solution. :)

What is $ch(G)$?

The choosability of G, i think its also known as the list chromatic number.

When you say “different approach”, do you still mean induction?

Not necessarily, I would be very interested in a solution using induction, but perhaps there better ways to solve it.

There are simpler ways to prove it: see the Wikipedia page on list colouring for example

Oh yes, thank you. But if anyone still has a suggestion for an induction proof, I would also be very happy to see it:)

I think induction is the wrong way to go -- why not prove it directly?
